# QGIS generate points at center of pixels

Tags: raster, pixel, qgis

I am using QGIS, and am trying to generate evenly spaces points at the center of each pixel in a raster layer. I am able to generate evenly spaced points but have not been able to get them close together enough or in the center of each pixel. Each pixel is supposed to be 1.85m, and is on a projected CRS in UTMs. I do not have access to ARIGIS. Is there a way to do this in QGIS? Or even in R? I tried generating a grid as well as generating points but the default distance is 0.0001 and whenever I try to go smaller it reverts automatically. I am also not sure how to interpret this default given that I am in UTMs.

Comment: maybe better suited for https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2.18 you can use the tool "Vectorial">"Research tools">"Regular points". You must choice the raster for input extention, spacing same to "spatial resolution of your raster" and with the option "initial offset from upper left corner" you put "0,5*spatial resolution of your raster" for create a layer of regular points with de center in every pixel of your raster.